# Move specific values in a python df based on a shared value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My current df:

```
clinical #     date collected      name       result      submitter

123                3/2/2020       flu a       negative      hospital

123                3/2/2020       flu b       positive      hospital

123                3/2/2020       flu c       positive      hospital

123                3/2/2020       flu d       negative      hospital

567                7/7/1945       flu a       negative      hospital

567                7/7/1945       flu b       negative      hospital

567                7/7/1945       flu c       positive      hospital

567                7/7/1945       flu d       negative      hospital

989                8/8/1988       flu a       negative      hospice 

989                8/8/1988       flu b       negative      hospice 

989                8/8/1988       flu c       negative      hospice 

989                8/8/1988       flu d       negative      hospice 

989                8/8/1988       flu e       negative      hospice 

989                8/8/1988       flu f       negative      hospice
```

My df has thousands of rows and the number of rows is always changing. Each person is represented by a number in column one, example: Jane is represented by 123. Jane was tested for  flu a, flu b, flu c, and flu d. I want Jane's information condensed into one row. I need the variables that vary between the rows AKA "name" and "result". All other information is constant and can be dropped. Some patients are tested for more values, like patient 989 who has 6 flu tests instead of 4 like Jane. Again, the same process would need to happen. Unique values like flu type and accompanying test result would be moved into the same row.

Ideal data frame would look like:

```
12      3/2/2020   hospital flu a -  flu b +   flu c -  flu d -  
567     7/7/1977   hospital flu a +  flu b +   flu c -  flu d -  
989     8/8/1988   hospital flu a -  flu b +   flu c -  flu d -  flu e +  flu f +
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this- like with a key or dictionary? I would so appreciate any viable solution.

Thanks in advance for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, create a concatented results text field using `map` to convert words to symbols for positive and negative, then `groupby` with `agg` function of `join`:

```
df['restxt'] = (df['collected'] + ' ' + 
                df['name'] + ' ' + 
                df['result'].map({'negative':'-', 'positive':'+'}))

df.groupby(['clinical #', 'date', 'submitter'], as_index=False)['restxt'].agg(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
   clinical #      date submitter                                           restxt
0         123  3/2/2020  hospital                  flu a - flu b + flu c + flu d -
1         567  7/7/1945  hospital                  flu a - flu b - flu c + flu d -
2         989  8/8/1988   hospice  flu a - flu b - flu c - flu d - flu e - flu f -
```